# Different behaviour of a function in shiny and in plain R?

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

So, I am working in R at a prediction algorithm and i have this dataset whose last 3 column are:

1. A "prior" probability of a given bigram.
2. The first piece of a bigram.
3. The second piece of a bigram.

A have a function that for the relevant bigrams (the ones whose first piece matches last words) updates the probability from a list of other meaningful words.

The function works locally.

```
caption <- "She's the sister of my "



probUpdate <- function(caption) {
  words <- unlist(strsplit(caption, " "))

  last <- words[length(words)]
  others <- words[-length(words)]



  chances <- dataset[which(dataset$lastWord == last),]

  for (j in 1:length(others)){
    if (others[j] %in% colnames(chances)){
      for (i in 1:nrow(chances)){
        chances[i, 1410] <- chances[i, 1410] * chances[i, which( colnames(chances)==others[j] )]
      }
    }
  }

  chances <- chances[order(chances[1410], decreasing = TRUE), ]
  return(chances[1, 1412])
}

probUpdate(caption)
```

This gives "husband.

But when I try to put it in a shiny app, the same input gives: "1464".

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
load(file = "PROGRESSING.RData")
source(file = "probUpdating.R")

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset)
  })



  output$caption <- renderText({
    probUpdate(input$caption)
  })

})
```

If i put:

```
output$caption <- renderText({
print(probUpdate(input$caption))
```

})

This shows me the right output in the console.

> argument 1 (type 'closure') cannot be handled by 'cat'

This is my ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Reactivity"),
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput("caption", "Caption:", "She's the sister of my")
  ),


  # Show the caption, a summary of the dataset and an HTML table with
  # the requested number of observation
  mainPanel(
    h3(textOutput("caption"))
  )
))
```

Any idea about why this is happening?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could be a `factor` issue. Sounds like your dataset has columns of type factor and `probUpdate` returns a factor. Factors are internally stored as integers pointing to a reference set. Maybe `renderText` does not interpret your factor number as the string it points to. Could you try out `as.character(probUpdate(input$caption)))`?

Answer (score 0):

renderPrint instead of renderText partially solves the issue.